# NSDateformatter for epoch value - Coreplot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot, nsdateformatter

Is the use of NSDateformatter required when I'm trying to plot the epoch values as time on the X-axis in coreplot?

Is there any sample code that I can refer to?

Comment: Yes Jef. I'm reading the value from a file as epoch value for x-axis. I tried plotting it but the graph doesn't appear properly. Sample code is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306947/using-epoch-time-on-the-x-axis-coreplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're looking for but you could always use [NSDate's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `timeIntervalSince1970` or `timeIntervalSinceDate:`